# Whats the difference and how to generate these two encodings?

Tags: php, string, encoding

I am working with these two encoding type of strings:

```
%ueb08%u8b09%u3c40%u5756%u5ebe%u3440%u408d
\x26\x04\x9e\x8e\xf9\xd0
```

To generate the first type I found this function:

```
function encoder(s)
{
    $res = strtoupper(bin2hex($s));
    $g = round(strlen($res)/4);
    if($g != (strlen($res)/4)) 
    $res .= "00"; 
    $out = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($res); $i += 4) 
    $out .= "%u" . substr($res, $i + 2, 2) . substr($res, $i, 2);
    return $out;
}
```

Now I need to convert the first type of strings, to the second type, which I don't even know what type of encoding it is. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom is just standard notation for representing hex values in the ascii space.

If you want the number 0, it is `\x00`, if you want 10, it would be `\x0A`, and 16 (hex's 10) is `\x10` (15 would be `\x0F`)

Comment: Same thing with the other one, it's unicode 16bit, %u signifying that it's unicode and the four letters being two bytes in hex.